# not(this) method won't work on buttons (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to make "Add Event" button appear and disappear with the coloring of the text when each text is clicked. Here when I click on a single text twice, it works(button appears and then disappears), but when I click on a text and then click on another text, the appeared "Add Event" button on the first text won't get removed when the next button appears. what I want is to create a button infront of the clicked text, and when the text is unselected, the button should be removed too.

```js
$('li').click(function() {

  $(this).addClass('abc');
  $(this).toggleClass('active abc');

  if ($('li').hasClass('active')) {
    $(this).append('<button type="button" class="bttn1">Add Event</button>');
  } else {
    $('button').remove();
  }

  $('li').not(this).removeClass('active abc');
});
```

```css
.active {
  color: red;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>Hello?</li>
  <li>Yes this is dog</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but is it because you're using `this` (dom element) instead of `$(this)` (jquery object)?

Comment: `if ($('li').hasClass('active'))` is not testing the element you clicked on, it's testing if *any* `<li>` has that class.

Comment: Your problem statement doesn't match your question..  you're not using `not(this)` on the button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

```
  if ($('li').hasClass('active')) {
```

is not looping through all the `<li>`, testing each of them and making this decision. It will be true if *any* `<li>` is active, and then it will add a button to the clicked `<li>` (even if it already has a button).

Do all the class updates first, and then you can use a selector to add the button after the selected `<li>`.

```js
$('li').click(function() {

  $(this).addClass('abc');
  $(this).toggleClass('active abc');
  $('li').not(this).removeClass('active abc');
  $('button.bttn1').remove();

  $('li.active').append('<button type="button" class="bttn1">Add Event</button>');
});
```

```css
.active {
  color: red;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>Hello?</li>
  <li>Yes this is dog</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Oh Now I Understand, thank you for the quick reply :)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like that ;-)

```
$('li').click(function() {

  $('li').removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active'); 

  $('button').remove();
  $(this).append('<button type="button" class="bttn1">Add Event</button>');

});
```

Comment: The `abc` class isn't being used for anything in the example, so I don't think it's relevant to the problem.

Comment: Of course, why i just delete that aspect of my answer.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. I see my mistakes now :)